# SQL Server over query

Tags: sql-server

My query returns the latest entry for each userid, but I need it to return the the latest entry for each userid and taskname. I tried to use group by, but I am getting an error. Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
SELECT UserId, TaskName, First, Last, email, ValueDate, Analysis
FROM (SELECT UserId, TaskName, First, Last, 
email, ValueDate, Analysis,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID
ORDER BY ValueDate DESC) AS rk
FROM MyTable) AS L
WHERE rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace **PARTITION BY UserID** with **PARTITION BY UserID, TaskName** :

```
SELECT UserId, TaskName, First, Last, email, ValueDate, Analysis
FROM (SELECT UserId, TaskName, First, Last, 
email, ValueDate, Analysis,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID, TaskName
ORDER BY ValueDate DESC) AS rk
FROM MyTable) AS L
WHERE rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having some data to test and tables structure, I can only presume what you really want to achieve but it could be something that look like this :

```
SELECT UserId, TaskName, First, Last, email, max(ValueDate), Analysis
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserId, TaskName, First, Last, email, Analysis
ORDER BY MAX(ValueDate) DESC
```